# how to increment and decrement the text box value using javascript?

Tags: javascript

i am trying increment and decrement a number if user is giving in text box is 15 it should be incremented when click a button and also decrement when button clicking...

this is my javascript code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function incNumber() {
        for(i=1;i>0;i++){
        document.getElementById("display").value=i;
    }
    }

    function decNumber() {
        for(i=1;i>0;i--){
        document.getElementById("display").value=i;
    }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="text" value="0"/>
    <input type="button" value="Increase" id="inc" onclick="incNumber()"/>
    <input type="button" value="Decrease" id="dec" onclick="decNumber()"/>

    <label id="display"></label>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `for(i=1;i>0;i++)` is an infinite loop

Comment: Remove for loops, they are not required. Simply, update the value everytime function is called.

Comment: you mean to increment the number ,if user has entered 15 as input else decrement ...is that what you want

Comment: if any number is giving the user in text box it should be increase when button clicks and decrease when another button clicks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parseInt()` function to convert the value from string to integer.

```
function incNumber(){
    var c = parseInt(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value);
    c++;
    document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = c;
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = c;
}
```

The logic stands for `decNumber()`

```
function decNumber(){
    var c = parseInt(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value);
    c--;
    document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = c;
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions 
1.Never mix up your markup with javascript. Consider attaching events click/change at javascript end

2. DOM search is costly.use it cautiously
   3.Use parseInt(variablename,10) ->to convert it into integer

check the following snippet

```js
window.onload=function(){
  var incButton=document.getElementById("inc");
  incButton.addEventListener("click",incNumber);
  var decButton=document.getElementById("dec");
  decButton.addEventListener("click",decNumber);
}
function incNumber() {
          var displayValue= document.getElementById("display");
  var text=document.getElementById("input");
  var value=parseInt(text.value,10);
  
  if(value==15){
       displayValue.innerHTML=value+1;
  }
}
    

    function decNumber() {
      var displayValue= document.getElementById("display");
  var text=document.getElementById("input");
  var value=parseInt(text.value,10);
        displayValue.innerHTML=value-1;
  
   }
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" value="0" id="input"/>
    <input type="button" value="Increase" id="inc" />
    <input type="button" value="Decrease" id="dec" />

    <label id="display"></label>
</form>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increment the label value by the input value try this

```
function incNumber(){
     var num=0;
     if(isNaN(document.getElementById('diplay').innerHTML)){
          num=$("#inputVal").val();
     }
     else{
          num=parseInt(document.getElementById('diplay').innerHTML)+$("#inputVal").val();
     }
     document.getElementById('diplay').innerHTML=num;
}

 function decNumber(){
     var num=0;
     if(isNaN(document.getElementById('diplay').innerHTML)){
          num=$("#inputVal").val();
     }
     else{
          num=parseInt(document.getElementById('diplay').innerHTML)-$("#inputVal").val();
     }
     document.getElementById('diplay').innerHTML=num;
}
```

In HTML

```
<form>
<input type="number" id="inputVal" value="0"/>
<input type="button" value="Increase" id="inc" onclick="incNumber()"/>
<input type="button" value="Decrease" id="dec" onclick="decNumber()"/>

<label id="display"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can define input type as number

```
<input type="number" id="numbrfield"/>
```

you will automatically get buttons to increment or decrement when you hover on the field.